Facebook app open all the links in Whatsapp Business
I am using a Remi 10 power device with Android 13. When I click on any post's chat on WhatsApp link in the Facebook app it opens the chat with WhatsApp business, not with my general WhatsApp app.
How do you think I could fix this?

Did you (accidentally) set WhatsApp Business as the default app when opening the link once, previously? If so, AFAIK, you have to reset default app preferences from Android Settings.

@AndrewT. I changed the default app preferences and it did not work in my case which should be working. I had to uninstall and install both the apps.
